# Reindexing missing dates in pandas but receiving NaN values

Tags: python, pandas

In pandas, I'm creating a dataframe like:

```
    df = pd.read_csv(file_path)[['timestamp', 'close']]
    df['close'] = df['close'].astype(float)
    df = df.set_index('timestamp')
```

The data looks like:

```
                    close
timestamp                 
2019-04-18          203.86
2019-04-17          203.13
2019-04-16          199.25
2019-04-15          199.23
2019-04-12          198.87
```

Now, I would like to fill in the missing `timestamp` and `close` values with linear interpolation from the nearest neighbors.

I created a list of the missing dates with:

```
dates = pd.date_range(start=df['timestamp'].min(), end=df['timestamp'].max())
```

Then reindexed with:

```
df = df.reindex(dates).iloc[::-1]
```

But this produced:

```
                      close
timestamp
2019-04-18             NaN
2019-04-17             NaN
2019-04-16             NaN
2019-04-15             NaN
2019-04-14             NaN
```

I was hoping this would at least copy over the previous values (although, I've yet to find a good way to get the missing close value interpolation handled smoothly.)
How would I phrase this in pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
df = df.set_index('timestamp')
df.resample('D').interpolate(method='index')
```

Output:

```
             close
timestamp         
2019-04-12  198.87
2019-04-13  198.99
2019-04-14  199.11
2019-04-15  199.23
2019-04-16  199.25
2019-04-17  203.13
2019-04-18  203.86
```

Answer (score 1):

Your index should not be datetime format , if you just using read_csv and does not pass `parse_dates`

```
df = df.set_index('timestamp')
df.index=pd.to_datetime(df.index)
```

After convert it , you should be fine with `reindex`

---

Another solution will be

```
df = pd.read_csv(file_path,parse_dates = 'timestamp')[['timestamp', 'close']]
```

---

After we finish convert the datetime,

We using `interpolate` fillna

```
df.loc[dates[::-1]].interpolate('index')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df.reindex(dates).align(df)[1]
```

Output:

```
+-------------+--------+
|             | close  |
+-------------+--------+
| 2019-04-12  | 198.87 |
| 2019-04-13  | NaN    |
| 2019-04-14  | NaN    |
| 2019-04-15  | 199.23 |
| 2019-04-16  | 199.25 |
| 2019-04-17  | 203.13 |
| 2019-04-18  | 203.86 |
+-------------+--------+
```